# Apache htaccess rewrite root and all root folders to subfolder without redirecting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ /subdir/ [L,NC]
```

I want to rewrite the root domain to subfolder without changing the URL in the browser. The above code works just for the root domain but not any folders and files.

For example, I have `https://example.com/` and `https://example.com/subdir/`.

With the above code in `.htaccess` file, when I go to `https://example.com/` I see the contents of `https://example.com/subdir/` which is good.

But when I go to `https://example.com/test.txt` I should see `https://example.com/subdir/test.txt` but I get The requested URL was not found on this server.

Same happens when I go to `https://example.com/abc` expecting to see contents of `https://example.com/subdir/abc`

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ /subdir/ [L,NC]
> ```

Change this to read:

```
RewriteRule !^subdir/ subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Any request that does *not* start `/subdir/` is internally rewritten to `/subdir/<url>`. The `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path (including the slash prefix).

I removed the slash prefix from the *substitution* string since you have defined a `RewriteBase /`. (Although neither are strictly necessary here.)

**UPDATE:**

> ...when I go to `example.com/s` I am being redirected to `example.com/subdir/s/`
> `s` is a subfolder within `subdir`, does that make any difference?

Ah yes, if `/s` is a subdirectory then mod_dir will append the trailing slash (to "fix" the URL) with an external 301 redirect. This redirect occurs after the URL has been rewritten to `/subdir/s` - thus exposing the `/subdir` subdirectory.

To handle this situation we can add another rule (a redirect) *before* the existing rewrite that first checks whether the request would map to a directory within the `/subdir` subdirectory and append a slash if it is omitted (before mod_dir would append the slash to the rewritten URL).

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

This states... for any request that:

- `!\.\w{2,4}$` - does not contain (what looks like) a file extension of between 2 and 4 characters (assuming your directories aren't named this way)
- `!/$` - and does not currently end in a slash.
- `-d` - and exists as a physical directory in the `/subdir` subdirectory.
- **THEN** redirect to append the trailing slash on the original request

Whilst this probably should be a 301 (permanent) redirect, you should first test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing, since the erroneous 301 redirect from `/s` to `/subdir/s/` will have been cached by the browser.

A potential *optimisation* is to remove the filesystem check and simply assume that any request that does not contain a file extension should map to a directory. (But this depends on whether you are handling these URLs in any other way.)

### Summary

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# If the requested URL exists as a directory in "/subdir" then append a slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Rewrite everything to "/subdir"
RewriteRule !^subdir/ subdir%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Many thanks. 

This works for https://example.com/, https://example.com/test.txt and https://example.com/s/ but does not work for https://example.com/s because when I go to https://example.com/s I am being redirected to https://example.com/subdir/s/

Comment: Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Maybe there's a conflict. As far as this directive goes, there's no difference between `https://example.com/s` and `https://example.com/test.txt`.

Comment: s is a subfolder within subdir, does that make any difference.

Comment: Ah yes, if `/s` is a subdirectory then mod_dir will append the trailing slash (to "fix" the URL) and trigger an external 301 redirect. Hence the redirect to `/subdir/s/`. We can perhaps add additional directives if this is a problem? Exactly how we do this really depends on your filesystem and what you require. Eg. Are you only serving real files and directories from `/subdir`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the issue of requesting a subdirectory (of the `/subdir` directory) without a trailing slash.